# Redux: using different container's actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

Is it okay for containerA to use containerB's actions? For example, both containerA and B need to fetch `data` from remote server and you define fetching-related functions inside containerA's directory.

```
containerA
  aContainer.js
  aActions.js
  aReducers.js

containerB
  bContainer.js
  bActions.js
  bReducers.js
```

Is it okay to `import ../containerA/aActions` inside `containerB/bContainer.js`?

Comment: Actions don't necessarily belong to a certain container. You chose to put them under "containerA", but you could have them under "appActions" instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely.

Imagine a `NavBar` container. It has an `openNav` and a `closeNav` action. Calling that from a different container conceptually makes a lot of sense:

```
import { openNav, closeNav } from '../NavBar/actions';
```

With data fetching, I opt to have one "global" container around the entire app. (I call it `App`) which takes care of global styles (since I use CSS modules), data fetching, etc.

Comment: Did this answer your question, or do I need to clarify something?